# Disable Factorio GUI info tooltip

Tags: factorio

What Factorio mod or setting do I need to turn off to prevent this tooltip from displaying? I can't figure out how I turned it on and it's interfering with my game.

I have many mods loaded and it takes many minutes to restart every time, so the process of figuring out which mod it might be is laborious. I've searched the internet for keywords that might guide me, and have come up short.

[image: Factorio GUI info tooltip]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be the option "GUI style view" whose default key-binding is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image]

I discovered by trying web searches including “factorio gui debug”, which led me to [this forum post](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?t=71249).

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I looked for debug settings and I swear I tried them all, something like F4 through F9 plus control, shift, and alt versions, but I must have missed it somehow.